# CSS Border Animation Works For Whole Div Content

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a border and forms inside of it. I decided to animate the border so it would pulse. My Code:

```
<div class="main">
<div class="border">

-Text Here-

</div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
@keyframes pulse {
  0% { opacity: 0;  animation-timing-function: ease-in;}
  20% { opacity: .2; animation-timing-function: ease-in;}
  40% { opacity: .4; animation-timing-function: ease-in;}
  45% { opacity: .8; animation-timing-function: ease-in;}
  50%% { opacity: 1; animation-timing-function: ease-in;}
  50%% { opacity: 1; animation-timing-function: ease-out;}
  55% { opacity: .8; animation-timing-function: ease-out;}
  60% { opacity: .4; animation-timing-function: ease-out;}
  80% { opacity: .2; animation-timing-function: ease-out;}
  100% { opacity: 0; animation-timing-function: ease-out;}
}

.border {
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 8px solid #2C3E50;
  animation-name: pulse;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}  

.main{
  padding: 50px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

The problem is that the animation works for the whole content of the div + the border, I would like it to work for only the border not the content inside of it. I know this is probably an easy fix, but I'm not good with CSS.

Also, how would I make the animation start when the user click anywhere inside the div and keep going even when click outside div. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `opacity` which will affect the entire div, use `border-color`.  [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aarpe0tv/).

```
@keyframes pulse {
        0%   { border-color: rgba(0, 255, 255, 1); }
        50%  { border-color: rgba(0, 255, 255, 0); }
        100% { border-color: rgba(0, 255, 255, 1); }
}

.border {
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 8px solid #2C3E50;
  animation: pulse 2s infinite;
}
```

If you want to toggle on & off when that specific div is clicked you could toggle the class with a function like:

```
function changeclass() {
   var blah = document.getElementById("border")
   if (blah.className=="border"){
       blah.className = "";
   }
   else{
       blah.className="border";
   }
}
```

and your html would be:

```
<div class="main">
<div id="border" onclick="changeclass()">
-Text Here- 
</div>
</div>
```

If you want to toggle on when clicked inside and then toggled off when clicked anywhere on the page, then add an eventlistener to the document like this:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;   
        if (target.className == "border"){
            target.className = "";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("border").className = "border";
        }
}, false);
```

and your html would be:

```
<div class="main">
<div id="border">
-Text Here-
</div>
</div>
```

Opacity is the 4th position in rgba so use 0.0-1.0 as the value.  Less being more transparent.

Comment: Thank you, it works! Do you know how I could start the animation when the user click inside the div? Also, can I do border-color: opacity: ?

Comment: @RomanK I edited my answer to give you two different ways to do it and the opacity thing is mentioned at the end.